# "Зодиакальное расположение Солнца" - такое возможно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Контекст не нужен. Хотелось бы знать, может ли Солнце располагаться зодиакально...

Контекст по просьбе трудящих:

> Под фронтонами порталов этих павильонов тени гномонов неслышно
>   скользят по полям солнечных часов, давая указания на время, сезон,
>   зодиакальное расположение Солнца и на другие важные мореплавателям
>   знаки.

Comment: _Galina Avanesova: Контекст не нужен._ === **Нужен!**

Comment: Слава, если Вы произнесли "нужен", я беспрекословно добавлю. А Вы потом шепните, помог ли он.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Контекст *нужен*: само по себе выражение "Солнце располагается зодиакально" не имеет смысла. А вот в контексте указания на то, в каком именно знаке Зодиака располагается Солнце тогда-то, оно возможно (*зодиакально Солнце* нынче *расположено* там-то). Из книжки "Самые интересные места мира" (Москва, АСТ, 2017):

> [Пражские куранты] *Находятся они на башне Староместской ратуши и*
>   *показывают три часовых измерения (среднеевропейское, старочешское и*
>   *звёздное время), а также указывают **зодиакальное расположение Солнца** и*
>   *Луны*.

Comment: Саша, добавлю контексту немедля! По-моему, предложение частично списано с Вашего ответа! )))